Compilation error while using while angular library
I migrated my angular 15 library to angular 17 and also upgraded primeng version from 15 to 17. While using the angular 17 library in angular 17 application I am getting the following error, Angular compilation initialization failed. [plugin angular-compiler] Error: Cannot resolve type entity i8.SidebarModule to symbol
Anyone has any idea on this?
I gave preserveSymlinks": true in angular.json build options, still I am getting same error
